# Codeigniter subdomains sharing one common app

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a domain set up: www.domain.com, that runs a codeigniter website.

I want a subdomain with the exact same website (except a different view for the footer) running at a subdomain www.sub.domain.com.

I currently have the exact same files under the sub domain folder, which works fine, but I do not want to update a whole bunch of folders for each subdomain.

Comment: If they are both on the same server, you can edit the `index.php` and point both apps to the same `system` folder.

Comment: I have them on the same server, and my subdomain is pointing to the main domain. When I type in www.sub.domain.com, it just goes to www.domain.com. How can I set up the index.php file so the subdomain shows up in the url. Changing the base_url wont work since the files are located under the main domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that www.domain.com and www.sub.domain.com are pointing to the same location on your server (this will be an apache configuration). You can then verify the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] variable to know if the user came through www.domain.com or www.sub.domain.com - then display to footer accordingly.

Comment: this is what I was thinking, but I can't get the sub domain name to show in the url: it just shows the main domain in the url, but I cant change the base url because all the files are under the main domain.

Answer (score 0):

Point your sub domain to your Main server ,then on your controller extract the sub domain,then just loop it like this

```
if (domain)
{
//load default..
}
else if(sub_domain)
{
//load default with your change..
}
```

This is not the correct syntax ,just the logic,hope it will help u.